# Why do I need to link my code to boost when compiling, if I already link to an intermediary .so file?

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, linker

I've written a library that relies on boost (particularly boost::system and boost::serialization) and compiled it as a shared object file (.so). My goal was to avoid having to link to boost every time I used the code, and just link to my lib instead. However, if I don't pass the  `-lboost_serialization` and `-lboost_system` flags to my compiler, I get undefined references to symbols (`DSO Missing from command line`). I'm not calling anything from boost directly, just objects from wrapper lib. Why is this happening and how can I circumvent this?

Comment: If you use library `a` that uses library `b`, you (usually) need to link both `a` and `b`.

Comment: Shared library in unix systems are quite different to DLLs on windows. Without further specific actions, for example, they also export all their symbols, opening the door to namespace pollution. Also - maybe due to the way elf works, they do not have explicit dependency information on other libraries, which could or would be used by the loader.

Comment: well to *circumvent* the error you can build a stub version of your library (contains all the symbols but no real code and no dependencies). Link against the stub, then at run time use the real one. you can build such a library automatically from a list of symbols.

Comment: @BitTicker what *specific* property of Unix DSOs makes it necessary to list deep dependencies in the link command?

Comment: what if I packed the static versions of those boost libraries (I had to compiled them manually anyway due to other issues) into my lib and link it dynamically?

Comment: @joaocandre then you wouldn't have to specify them when linking ypour executable.